# How to add multiple user controls to Accordion in xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml, accordion

I'm using a Silverlight 4 page with an Accordion to which I'm trying to insert 2 user controls to each Accordion item.

```
<toolkit:Accordion Name="accordion1">
    <toolkit:AccordionItem Content="item 1" Header="A">
        <local:AddRemoveControl x:Name="AddRemoveAgents" Margin="470,90,0,0">     </local:AddRemoveControl>
    </toolkit:AccordionItem>
    <toolkit:AccordionItem Content="item 2" Header="B -  long header">
        <local:DatesFilter x:Name="DatesFilter" Margin="475,200,0,0" Canvas.Top="76"> </local:DatesFilter>
    </toolkit:AccordionItem>
</toolkit:Accordion>
```

I'm getting the following error message: "The property content is set more than once"

How can I proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you maybe group the controls in a stack panel, and set the stack panel as the Accordions content?

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one content item in an accordion.

What you will need to do is wrap your controls in a StackPanel:

```
<toolkit:Accordion Name="accordion1">
    <toolkit:AccordionItem Content="item 1" Header="A">
        <StackPanel>
            <local:AddRemoveControl x:Name="AddRemoveAgents" Margin="470,90,0,0"></local:AddRemoveControl>
            <local:DatesFilter x:Name="DatesFilter" Margin="475,200,0,0" Canvas.Top="76"> </local:DatesFilter>
        </StackPanel>
    </toolkit:AccordionItem>
</toolkit:Accordion>
```

Comment: @dana - can you edit your updated code into your question - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5324581/edit - don't replace the original code though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code:

```
<toolkit:Accordion Canvas.Left="480" Canvas.Top="104" Height="100" Name="accordion1" Width="300">
        <toolkit:AccordionItem Content="item 1" Header="A">
                <StackPanel>
                    <local:AddRemoveControl x:Name="AddRemoveAgents" Margin="470,90,0,0"></local:AddRemoveControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </toolkit:AccordionItem>
        <toolkit:AccordionItem Content="item 2" Header="B -  long header">
                <StackPanel>
                    <local:DatesFilter x:Name="DatesFilter" Margin="475,200,0,0" Canvas.Top="76"></local:DatesFilter>
                </StackPanel>
        </toolkit:AccordionItem>
    </toolkit:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the content twice.  Try removing the content tags from the AccordionItem like this:

```
<toolkit:Accordion Canvas.Left="480" Canvas.Top="104" Height="100" Name="accordion1" Width="300">
    <toolkit:AccordionItem Header="A">
            <StackPanel>
                <local:AddRemoveControl x:Name="AddRemoveAgents" Margin="470,90,0,0"></local:AddRemoveControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </toolkit:AccordionItem>
    <toolkit:AccordionItem Header="B -  long header">
            <StackPanel>
                <local:DatesFilter x:Name="DatesFilter" Margin="475,200,0,0" Canvas.Top="76"></local:DatesFilter>
            </StackPanel>
    </toolkit:AccordionItem>
</toolkit:Accordion>
```

Also, the way you have it currently you will end up with two Accodion items with one control in each.  To get both the controls in the same item you need to put the second control in the first stackpanel.

```
<toolkit:Accordion Canvas.Left="480" Canvas.Top="104" Height="100" Name="accordion1" Width="300">
<toolkit:AccordionItem Header="A">
     <StackPanel>
          <local:AddRemoveControl x:Name="AddRemoveAgents" Margin="470,90,0,0">                                        
      </local:AddRemoveControl>
          <local:DatesFilter x:Name="DatesFilter" Margin="475,200,0,0" Canvas.Top="76">
          </local:DatesFilter>
     </StackPanel>
 </toolkit:AccordionItem>
```

Comment: Have you found a resolution yet?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried your suggested code. The accordion appears but I'm afraid that my controls are not displayed within the accordion items. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: It could be an issue with the margins. Try setting the margins relative to the stackpanel instead of the canvas.